# Independence and functions of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables. Let $U=f_1(X,Y)$ and $V=f_2(X,Y)$ be two new random variables. Is it true that $U$ and $V$ are independent? If not are there conditions on $f_1$ and $f_2$ that make them independent?

Comment: In general, no.  A trivial counterexample:  choose $f_1 = f_2$; then $U = V$ and they are perfectly correlated random variables.  But if we choose $f_1 = X$, $f_2 = Y$, then $U = X$, $V = Y$, and $U, V$ inherit their independence from $X, Y$.

Comment: Do you mean $U = f_1(X,Y), V = f_2(X,Y)$?

Comment: There is no reason to suppose they are independent. Here is an extreme example. Let $f_1(x,y)=y$, $f_2(x,y)=y^3$. Indeed for most joint distributions, and most $f_1,f_2$, $f_1(X,Y)$ and $f_2(X,Y)$ are  not independent.

Answer (score 1):

In general the statement is not true.

Just take a random variable X which is not independent from itself, for example a Bernoulli($1/2$). Then just define $ f_1(x,y) = x, f_2(x,y) = x $. It is clear then that $U$ and $V$ are not independent as $U = V = X$ and $X$ is not independent from itself.

In a sense the statement does not seem to be intuitive in any context, as in general both $U$ and $V$ use information of both variable. A sufficient condition for independence is that $f_1$ depends only of the first coordinate and $f_2$ depends only of the second coordinate, but is not really interesting.